# Removing Members in Groups in Azure AD Powershell Automatically (App API Permission)

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, scripting, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to remove members of groups automatically via a PowerShell Script.
There's an Azure AD app created, with `User.ReadWrite.All` (Application) and as User administrator (service principal) permissions. I'm doing several steps in this script, so don't wonder about the several logons:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MgGraph
...differentTasks...
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId '...' -memberId '...' 
...someMoreTasks...
```

The response is:

```
Remove-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing RemoveGroupMember 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list.
```

Comment: Ummm, do you have a question regarding this?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: I think this was just a translation problem. Where they said, "The answer is", what they meant was "The response is", as they're providing an error message. I've made an [edit] to the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment, and I am able to remove the members from the Azure AD group successfully like below command:**

```
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 'Your_Object_Id' -memberId 'Your_Member_Id'
```

[image]

You can refer to the script mentioned in this [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2344276-remove-user-from-all-mail-enabled-groups?utm_campaign=item&utm_medium=rss&utm_source=global) if you want to remove **mailenabled** users.

```
$email = "user.mail@domain.com"
$AzureMember = get-azureaduser -objectid $email | Select objectId
$AzureMember | Get-AzureADUserMembership | Where-Object {($_.ObjectType -eq "Group") -and ($_.MailEnabled -eq $True)} | ForEach-Object {
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -MemberId $AzureMember.ObjectId -InformationAction Continue
}
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[I am trying to add member in mail enabled security group using graph api, Is that possible? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/608720/i-am-trying-to-add-member-in-mail-enabled-security.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I tested it with a different group type - when i choose the "real" azureadgroup, everything worked fine than ... thanks for you help.